# HTML Bullet point with no indent

Tags: html, inline

I'm creating an html email and want to create bullet points without indent.
Because it's an email it has to be html and inline CSS. Is there a way to edit your bullet settings? These are multi line bullets.

Comment: what did you try that didn't work? `li { margin-left: -10px; }`?

Answer (score 14):

Just put `&bull;` at the start of the line, instead of a list:

```
&bull; List item here<br />
&bull; Another list item here
```

Renders as:

• List item here
• Another list item here

This way you can be sure it will be consistent across email clients.

Comment: @JohnB, Its not that "anything goes" in email, but that css is not widely supported across email clients. Therefore, we resort to hacks to get the job done, just like previous generations of web designers used tables for layout before browsers supported css.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign a choice of two properties to alter position of bullet points:

`list-style-position: outside;
list-style-position: inside;`

Then adjust padding accordingly.

See this [example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/impressivewebs/pen/tIEKG).

You will still need to deal with display differences within individual email clients however.

Comment: This is ill-advised - it won't be supported in an appreciable fraction of the market share http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 5):

Just set the ULs margin and padding to zero.

```
<ul style="margin:0;padding:0">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unordered list tag has a default padding assigned to it, you can override it by giving `margin-left: -10px` css. this should resolve your issue.

On giving a 0px padding you will end up losing your bullets.

Thanks